# Checking out a remote branch into a new branch

Tags: git, github, branch

Goal: `git checkout -b newBranchName remotes/branchForRemote/main` to actually go into `newBranchName`

I started with an empty Git repository, which I cloned from github.com.

Then, `git remote add [urlFromAnOpenSourceProject]`

Then, `git checkout -b newBranchName remotes/openSourceRepo/main`.

The command above only pulled the `remotes/openSourceRepo/main` into my own main branch. How do I instead make it pull into another of my branches (not my main branch)?

Note: I have a workaround listed below, but I would still like to know how to avoid needing to use this workaround.

My workaround: Create/switch to a different branch, and then run the following commands

```
brew install git-lfs (if you need git-lfs for your open source project)
git clone [My repository URL]
git remote add opensource [Open source URL]
git fetch opensource
git lfs install (if the open source project uses it.)
git checkout -b branchToPullinto
git checkout -b nameThatWillNotBeUsed remotes/opensource/main
git commit -m “I pulled from opensource into the branchToPullinto branch”
git push -> Will throw an error
git push --set-upstream origin anotherNewBranch
The Command Prompt/Terminal will say:
Branch 'anotherNewBranch' set up to track remote branch 'anotherNewBranch' from 'origin'.
Now, run “git push”
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is about right. You just forgot a `git fetch --all` or `git fetch <open source remote name you gave it in remote add>`.

So basically:

1. `git clone https://github.com/<url to your empty repo>`
2. `git remote add opensource <link to open source project>`
3. `git fetch opensource`
4. `git checkout -b <any name you want> opensource/master`

Without `git fetch`, your Git installation doesn't know which files/branches/tags your open source remote has in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, ParSal! This is very helpful and brought me to the solution! I've discovered that regardless of what I go, the #4 command you mentioned always pulls into the current branch, so all I have to do is create/switch to a different branch, and then run the #4 command you suggested. I'll post my steps separately. Thank you! This was very helpful!